# Conan linter giving deprecated method linter error for method shown in the docs

Tags: conan

With Conan 2.0 I'm getting a linter error when I push a recipe to Conan Center

```
Run echo "::add-matcher::linter/recipe_linter.json"
************* Module conanfile
Error: recipes/azure-storage-cpp/all/conanfile.py:6: [E9010(conan-import-error-conaninvalidconfiguration), ] Import ConanInvalidConfiguration from new module: `from conan.errors import ConanInvalidConfiguration`. Old import is deprecated in Conan v2.
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

This implies that the `ConanInvalidConfiguration` method is old and should not be used, but I can see it in the [Conan 2.x docs](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/conanfile/methods/validate.html?highlight=ConanInvalidConfiguration).

What should I use instead of `ConanInvalidConfiguration`?

Comment: ``ConanInvalidConfiguration`` is still valid, maybe it is the ``from conans`` namespace. The correct way to import it is ``from conan`` (as everything in recipes to be compatible with Conan 2.0). If this doesn't help, it would be worth to file a ticket as  Github issue in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues

Comment: The Conan package azure-storage-cpp is still not ported to Conan 2.x, but working only with Conan 1.x. It should be updated at some point by the community. You could open an issue on https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues asking for an update, or, taking an adventure by trying to update that recipe with a new PR.